# Local variable in Unittest subtest is not defined

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a test task for unittest. I get the NameError `error: name 'x' is not defined` in each subtest.
After looking at the course material and documentation, I can't figure out what the error is. How do I fix this?

```
    import unittest


    def factorize(x):
        """
        Factorize positive integer and return its factors.
        :type x: int,>=0
        :rtype: tuple[N],N>0
        """
        pass


    class TestFactorize(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_wrong_types_raise_exception(self):
            cases = ['string', 1]
            for case in cases:
                with self.subTest(x=case):
                    print(x)
                    self.assertRaises(TypeError, factorize, x)

        def test_negative(self):
            cases = [-1, -10, -100]
            for case in cases:
                with self.subTest(x=case):
                    self.assertRaises(ValueError, factorize, x)

        def test_zero_and_one_cases(self):
            cases = [0, 1]
            for case in cases:
                with self.subTest(x=case):
                    self.assertEqual(factorize(x), (x,))

        def test_simple_numbers(self):
            cases = [3, 13, 29]
            for case in cases:
                with self.subTest(x=case):
                    self.assertEqual(factorize(x), (x,))


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subtest` doesn't define a new local variable `x`. `x` is just a name used as part of the error message when the test fails. You need, for example, to continue to use `case` in your test code itself.

```
def test_wrong_types_raise_exception(self):
    cases = ['string', 1]
    for case in cases:
        with self.subTest(x=case):
            print(case)
            self.assertRaises(TypeError, factorize, case)
```

Now when the test fails, you'll see each subtest labeled with string like `x=...`, with the value of `case` that produced the failure.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_wrong_types_raise_exception (__main__.TestFactorize) (x='string')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 19, in test_wrong_types_raise_exception
    self.assertRaises(TypeError, factorize, case)
AssertionError: TypeError not raised by factorize
```

Changing the call to `subTest(foo=case)` would cause the tag to become `foo='string'`.